# Kafka Connect duplicating messages in topic after setting sourceOffset, unique key, log compaction

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I tried to do something like the following:

```
public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
  List<SourceRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();

  JSONArray jsonRecords = getRecords(0, 3);

  for (Object jsonRecord: jsonRecords) {
   JSONObject j = new JSONObject(jsonRecord.toString());

   Map sourceOffset = Collections.singletonMap("block", j.get("block").toString());
   Object value = j.get("data").toString();

   records.add(new SourceRecord(
    Collections.singletonMap("samesourcepartition", "samesourcepartition"), // sourcePartition
    sourceOffset, // sourceOffset
    "mytopic", // topic
    Schema.STRING_SCHEMA, // keySchema
    j.get("block").toString, // key: "0", "1", "2", "3"
    Schema.STRING_SCHEMA, // valueSchema
    value // value
   ));

   log.info("added record for block: " + j.get("block"));
  }

  log.info("Returning {} records", records.size());

  return records;
}
```

I am confused about how to use the `sourceOffset`.(https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html#task-example-source-task)

An example of `block` could be `"3"`. I would expect it to be the case that if Kafka has already read this `sourceOffset`, it should not read it again. But it seems to completely ignore this and the `offset` continue to grow way past 3 and keep repeating the same 0-3 data in an infinite loop. For example, if I look at the Confluent dashboard > Topics > Inspect I would expect the highest `offset` and `key` recorded to be "3" but it's over 100+ with duplicated keys and values.

Does my poll() need to be incrementing the 0->3 so it knows when to "stop"? The current behavior keeps repeating 0->3, 0->3, ... to add `new SourceRecord()`, but I imagine with `sourceOffset` and the unique `key` should be idempotent.

I am sure I am misunderstanding something. I also tried to turn on `log compaction`, but still getting duplicates even with the same key. Can someone show the proper use to have a message per `sourceOffset`/`key`?

Comment: Kafka isn't a key-value database; every message (including the key) is a unique event.

With regards to compaction, it won't stop a equal key from being produced, or replace existing messages. Plus, compaction occurs periodically, not immediately, so multiple keys between compaction events are still possible.

Comment: I don't quite understand. I'm going to review a source connector that I know works properly like JDBC to study the behavior, but this would mean that if I had 3 rows in a table with id (1, 2, 3) and the `sourceOffset` was being set to track that id, it would still read those over and over again putting the exact same rows as new unique events.

Comment: Without seeing your internal logic for `getRecords(0, 3)`, all I can say here is that you are going to get those same records for every poll... And similarly for JDBC connector in bulk mode, yes, it does scan the entire table each time. To overcome that, you would use the incrementing timestamp mode, so the `sourceOffset` is the last timestamp that was queried.

Comment: I think what would help clear things up for me is the question: How does `poll()` know where to resume and how does it know when it is done? Or is it never done?

Comment: Let's take the `getRecords(start, stop)` example to represent page numbers. Should my `poll()` function be incrementing some variable to keep track of what it read last, or is it expected that it runs start -> stop, over and over again? Should it be `poll => 0 (track 0), poll => 1 (track 1), poll => 2 (track 2), poll => 3 (track 3)` or should it be `poll => 0-3, poll => 0-3, poll => 0-3`? The latter does not make sense to me say if you had 1,000,000 records instead of 3 and duplicates data.

Comment: Should `context.offsetStorageReader().offset(sourcePartition)` only be used once at `start()` to initialize last seen variables or should it be used on every `poll()`?

Comment: This is some of the code I've been studying: https://github.com/simplesteph/kafka-connect-github-source/blob/master/src/main/java/com/simplesteph/kafka/GitHubSourceTask.java It looks like it 1. initializes last seen variables at `start()` 2. keeps track of pages in `poll()` to move through the data and 3. I'm not sure what it does once it reaches the end of the data. It looks like it would return an empty `records = []` because there is no more to fetch, which would wipe the topic?

Comment: I haven't implemented my own connector, but I do think you need to track what has already been produced if you need to prevent duplicates. And `records = []` would simply send no data for that iteration of the poll method. The data in the topic cannot be deleted from a Connector

Comment: I am actually seeing behavior where if my `poll()` errors or reaches the last page and if I `return null;` or return an empty `List<SourceRecord>`, it cleans all the data in my topic... but I will make sure I am not doing anything stupid here because it would make a lot more sense, as you said, if it simply sends no data! Thanks, and I will report back!

Comment: I have implemented my own Source Connector, where i read data from Oracle database and published it to Kafka topic(n-partitions). They way I do it is if topic has n-partitions then I create connector with n-tasks. To make sure I am not pulling same data in every task I use "Mod" condition in where clause when firing a query, something like   ``Where MOD (<your_primary_id>, <max_tasks>) = <current_partition_number> and <your_primary_id> > <offset>`` 
In poll you need to get offset every time ``context.offsetStorageReader().offset(sourcePartition)``

Comment: So I was able to a working solution. Yes so it seems there is something awkward with the Confluent UI topics where it says "no messages" when there clearly are some, and I had to set "jump to offset" to see them, so things weren't being wiped. Putting logs in `commit()` helped me see that it was saving the wrong offset, and that it happens on about a 1 minute delay from when records are written, which was where a majority of my problems were.

Comment: I am not sure `poll()` needs to get the offset every time (https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/master/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/OffsetStorageWriter.java#L52), but I was able to implement the behavior I wanted by getting the last offset with `context.offsetStorageReader()` on `start()` which gets assigned to private variables `start` and `stop`, then poll uses those in `getRecords(start, stop)`, similar to the GitHub connector I linked above. I also noticed that loading/unloading new connectors would force a `commit()` and re-trigger `start()`.